# Display all taxonomy terms in a Select box - ACF Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to display all taxonomy terms in a select box (form) for my search engine.

With my code i can only display 1 but i want to see all.
I need also to display in a first choice the name of the taxonomy

```
<select name="chambre" class="form-control selectform" data-live-search="true">
<?php
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'chambre');
if ($terms) {
$output = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$output[] = '<option value="' . $term->name_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
}
echo join(' ', $output);
};
?>
</select>
```

Comment: This is working fine for me.

Comment: @Bhautik on my archive page, i have 10 houses with different config of 'chambre' (room), and in my select box, i only see the term of the first house and i need to see all terms